# How input a list of int pairs to a MySQL store procedure from C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

How input a list of int pairs to a MySQL store procedure from C#?

I have a list of 2500 int pairs and want to have it as input to be handheld as two columns in MySQL.
E.g. I want to send input.

```
List<IntPair> input = new List<IntPair>();

struct IntPair{
    int a;
    int b;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no IntPair-Type in MySQL. Use 2 different Int-parameters

```
using (MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection("ConnString"))
{
    myConnection.Open();
    foreach (var item in input)
    {                  
        using (MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand("spInputData", myConnection))
        {
            myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Parameter1", item.a);
            myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Parameter2", item.b);
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not an option since this will add an over head since i have to do multiple search for the same row instead of use the IN command. I have tested different approaches and doing one big search is much faster than many small. If this is not correct pleas state what i should change in what settings to remove the over head.

Comment: you can use a Multiple-Column Index to improve performance http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: Does not using index only help in general? Does it help when I have multiple queries vs one query?

Comment: it helps when you have a query over multiple columns (like 2 integer values in your IntPair object)

Comment: Good point! However I still need the list to be sent to the function. You stil did get an up vote even if it's not answer the problem.